# Can I import savegames from Tropico 4 to Tropico 4 Gold?

Tags: tropico-4

So far I played Tropico 4 without Modern Times, but now I purchased the Gold Edition containing basegame and expansion pack.

Is there any way I can copy my progress from the base game to the gold edition?

I already looked into `C:\\Users\Name\Application Data\Tropico 4[ Gold]\`. If I only copy the `users` folder in this directory I can choose my name from the base game, but progress is completely lost (achievements as well as campaign status and save games). If I instead copy the complete folder the save games and everything is there, but there is nothing left from the expansion pack (except that the version is 1.5 instead of 1.0).

Comment: Is this a physical copy or are you using Steam?

Comment: @sommerjj A physical copy.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I found the answer.

1. Backup the content of `Tropico 4 Gold` folder.
2. Move the whole folder from `Tropico 4` to `Tropico 4 Gold`
3. Copy the DLC folder from within the backup folder into the `Tropico 4 Gold` folder

The saved game and the expansion are then available at the same time.